# Can't Install Wine, held Packages

Tags: wine, package-management

I am getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20.2) but 204-5ubuntu20.4 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I've tried to apt-get dist-upgrade and I got the same message: 
The following packages have been kept back:
  libudev1 udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I am using ubuntu 64bits 14.04
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Answer (score 0):

1st command executed properly

the others didn't:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
E: The update command takes no arguments